# GWT Listbox with a hidden id column (and maybe even an additional viewable column)

Tags: java, gwt, listbox

I have the following case:
I need to have a listbox which displays Employees. An Employee, for this matter, has the following attributes- id, name and department_name. I want the ability to display the employee's name (and maybe even department_name) BUT when the user selects a record I want to have access to the employee's id (as it is the only unique identifier). I cannot use the id to view as it has no business meaning.
I'd preffer not to use any external libraries and in any case I don't want to use smartGWT.
Thanks in advance,
Ittai

Comment: Just to make it clear. I googled around and looked in the docs and couldn't find an obvious way so I'm asking here. It's not as if I haven't tried to tackle the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [GWT api](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/index.html), when you set a listbox item, you can set the "item" and the "value" as separate entities, which you can then get back via the indices:

```
ListBox list = new ListBox();
list.addItem("John Smith", 1);
list.addItem("Jane Doe", 2);

int index = list.getSelectedIndex(); /// assuming selected index is zero for example
list.getValue(index); // ----> returns "John Smith"
list.getItemText(index); // ------> returns "1"
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know where my head was when I was looking around... Do you happen to know if there is any way for me to display a second column? i.e. a listbox of two columns? or as an alternative an "alt" property for each row? I'll wait 'til tomorrow morning before I accept your answer as I hope someone might come up with the additional part.

Comment: If you want to do the second column, then I think you need to use the [CellList](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellList.html) with a CompositeCell of two TextCells (or a two column CellTable).  And since ListBox is just a <select> element, it doesn't do tooltips either unfortunately

Comment: Wow! thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I haven't gotten around to actually testing this but from the few resources I read it looks excellent. Thanks again and I'll post an update whether it really worked for me when I'll finish the small test

Comment: Actually list.getValue(index) returns "1" and list.getItemText(index) returns "John Smith". Moreover value is a String, so you should write list.addItem("name","value")